# Why do phase-shift oscillators appear to use high pass filters rather than low pass?

Tags: oscillator, phase-shift

I noticed that a lot of designs of phase-shift oscillators use a sequence of high-pass filters to get the phase-shift. Is there any reason why one couldn't use three low pass filters instead? I realize that the maximum phase-shift for a single high-pass filter is +90 and for a low-pass filter -90. Does this difference influence the design?

Comment: Think again, what is the criteria for oscillation using the Barkhausen Criteria?  Then what is the criteria to make it a stable Sine wave wave output?   Then what is the phase shift in  each RC with 3 stages.

Comment: the high-pass filters perform DC_blocking, thus a simple single transistor Common_emitter amplifier provides the power gain.

Comment: Here is one benefit of the high-pass version (assuming an opamp) : The resistor of the last C-R element can fulfill two tasks at the same time: It works (a) as an input resistor Rx as part of the inverting amplifier (gain: - Ry/Rx) and (b) as a grounded R (virtual ground) as required for a simple C-R highpass stage. This simplyfies the design of the whole oscillator. In contrast, when we are using a three-stage lowpass, the resistor Rx (as part of the amplifier) works as an - unwanted - load for the last R-C stage.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  to answer your question: "what is the phase shift in each RC with 3 stages" Up to 90 degrees for each one, so a max of 270. At a 45-degree shift, both are equivalent in terms of amplitude changes. Hence I was wondering if there was any advantage to one or the other. I've seen both designs but the high-pass one seems to dominate. Thinking more about it I wonder whether it because it's easier to get minimal amplitude change with a high-pass filter at larger frequency shifts. A low pass filter to exceed 180-degrees  would result in a fairly reduced amplitude.

Comment: @Lvw: Seems a resonable explanation.

Comment: @LvW  a 2 stage HPF may not satisfy the stable oscillation requirement. Which is why 3 stages are used.

Comment: In any of these classic (imperfect) phase shift designs there is a tolerance to attenuation at 3 stages to share 180 degree phase shift. Thus the gain to compensate this requires soft limiting to regulate it and precise gain control. 2 stage version wont work.  But you can use a 3 or more.  Here's another one http://tinyurl.com/yhm8b84f  Dont think of 270 deg phase shift. Look up the Barkhausen Criteria  This simulation uses 3 LPF but again R Ratios are critical

Comment: The reason I mention 270 degrees is just to emphasize that one needs the ability to pass 180 degrees at some frequency so you can hit 180 exactly (Second Barkhausen criterion). I'm thinking that with a low pass chain of filters the gain on the amplifier has to be that much more to compensate for the attenuation we see with such filters, something that doesn't happen with high-pass filters, in fact, the opposite.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 I liked that simulation you cited in your response. I don't think I was aware of that site.

Comment: Under Op Amps> Osc> phase shift .. you can find the classic HPF 3 stage. I made my own and then File> EXport link, but beware Zout =0 and ESR=0 so add when you want real impedance

Comment: I just found the phase-shift oscillator, very neat. This is a great resource.

Comment: Yes Falstad's is far better than what this site uses and easier than Lspice but ideal without part numbers, so you chose Beta etc but every part value can be turned into a "slider"

Comment: A high-pass has the advantage that the feedback above the oscillation frequency is strongly negative that helps reduce any harmonics that are generated in the amplifying stage. With a low-pass the output can be taken after the filter but that is low amplitude and high-impedance so less desirable.

Comment: @Tony Stewart..I do not understand your comment about a "2 stage HPF". Did I mention such a circuit? I cannot remember. By the way - a feedback circuit with a two-stage RC lowpass is one of the best phase-shift versions - when it works together with an inverting Miller intergator.

Comment: @Kevin White..I cannot follow your reasoning (..fedback above the oscillation frequency is strongly negative...). Why do you think that harmonics are better reduced?? (A high pass reduces harmonics?).

Comment: @LvW - the high-pass is in the negative feedback loop, so it reduces the gain of the amplifier at higher frequencies, ie harmonics.

Comment: @LvW I misunderstood , yes Integrator + 2 stage is OK,  same as my simulation.

Comment: @Kevin White..Harmonics are created in the amplifier (if the supply rail is used for amplitude regulation). A highpass in the feedback loop cannot reduce these harmonics...however, a lowpass can!! A proof is possible based on the harmonic balance method.

Comment: @LvW - I politely disagree.

Comment: @Kevin White...that is your proved right - however, without any justification? (The feedback loop is negative for DC only!! The loop gain for oscillation is POSITIVE !)